# CSS Multiple Background Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with having multiple backgrounds on the body of my page. Here's the css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/top-left.png), url(../img/top-right.png);
    background-position: top-left, top-right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `top-left, top-right` but `top left, top right`.